# C++ Accessing private structure of base in derive class

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, structure, private-members

```
class base
{
    struct struk1
    {
        int a1;  
    };

    struct struk1 s1;

public:

    base(int x)
    {              
        s1.a1 = x;          
    }  

    base() {}
};

class b : public base
{
    struct struk1 s2; // Works Fine    
    base::struk1 s3;  // Error is given => 'struct base::struk1' is private
    base b1;

public:     
    b(int x, int y) : base(y)
    {    
        s2.a1 = x;    // Works Fine
        b1.s1.a1 = x; // Error => 'base::struk1 base::s1' is private
    } 
}
```

In the above code, I am getting errors while accessing and creating objects of the structure which is under the `private` specifier in the `base` class.

Please tell me why I am able to create a structure variable directly but not by using the `base` class object in the derived class.

Comment: What compiler are you using? [Clang rejects your code with an expected error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2917984eabedbf68).

Comment: I used a web based compiler from http://cpp.sh/  The URL for my code is cpp.sh/4zfre/

Comment: It is mentioned on the site cpp.sh that  'The system uses GCC 4.9.2, with Boost 1.55 available'

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug to me.

Comment: Yes I checked it on Code Block & Visual studio and the above code gave error for 'struct struk1 s2; ' so the original issue was due to compiler bug at cpp.sh 's web compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring private type: struk1 in base class. This means this type will be accessible only in the base class. Then you declare private instance s1 of this type.

I am surprised that your compiler doesn't complain here:

```
struct struk1 s2; // Works Fine
```

You are declaring instance s2 of type struk1, which is PRIVATE, so derived class has no access to it. VS2013 compiler doesn't say it is works.

As above, you are refering to base::struk1 type which is private. This is internal class details, which are encapsulated within base class.

```
base::struk1 s3;  // Error is given => 'struct base::struk1' is private
```

Do you want derived classes have access to it, declare struk1 type as protected. If you want everyone could refer to this type as base::struk1, make it public.

In derived class you have declared s2 instance, so no problem accessing its a1 field via in derived class (assuming that you made struk1 type at least protected in base class:

```
s1.a1 = x;
```

Here we come to this line:

```
b1.s1.a1 = x; // Error => 'base::struk1 base::s1' is private
```

You declared b1 instance of base type in derived class. You try to access to its private instance s1. Private means it is visible within the class it is declared, so no wonder you can't access it externally. It doesn't matter you declared base b1 instance within derived class, you are trying to modify b1 private internals, which is not allowed. Making it protected doesn't help. You need to make it public if you want to do b1.s1.a1 = x;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is with compiler that I used to compile this code. I used an online compiler from cpp.sh which gave me the above result.  But after looking at the comments I compiled it gain using Code Block and the result was as expected. This line of code struct struk1 s2; which was working fine on cpp.sh compiler showed error on code block

Answer (score 1):

Private data members can be accessed only within the class in which they are declared.
Make them either public or protected if you want to access them in your derived classes.